# How to use object of a class which contain object of another class as datasource in jasper report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have two different classes, One is Person and another one is Address. 
The Person class has an object of Address class as one of its property. For example

```
class Person{
   String name;
   Address address;
}
```

I cannot change the structure of the class and cannot add any new collections because of other problems.

My problem is, I want to use objects of Person class as datasource for my *JasperReports*'s report 
which has fields from both Person and Address Class. Can Somebody Please Help

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is the relevant section of your .JRXML file?  Please post that.  Presumably, `Person` has a `getAddress()` method and both `Person` and `Address` have getters for the fields that you want included in your report.  Are you calling those methods from within your report definition?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So far, my jrxml file contains nothing but text fields for properties in both Person and Address class. I map the data to report from my java program by using JrBeanCollectionDatasource. And yes of course using the getter methods of class only the data is fetching. if I use Person class object without Address object inside it, all the fields of the Person class will be filled. But I dont know how to access fields in address class using the object in the Person class when mapping it to the jasper report.

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing the JRXML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

1. Declare only the instances variables of the Person class as jasper reports fields: one field will be "name" of type java.lang.String and another field will be "address" of type your.package.Address (that's it).
2. Then, if you want to print address specific information in the report, create a Text Field square where you want such info to be displayed and use the expression editor to write something like this: $F{address}.getZipCode() (assuming that Address class has such method and you want to print such info)...

Hope this help...

Comment: thank you so much. this is exactly what i wanted. its working too. once again thanks.

Comment: how to import the "yourpackage.Address" in class properties ? Because I cannot browse my java class through the dialog.